# Best way to keep the elements of a structure up to date

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry if the title is not clear. I had no better idea.

I want to store in Python a "list" of entries. An entry consists of a date and a location. All I want to do is to maintain the list up to date by removing regularly all entries older than 24 hours.

What is the best way to store the entries (dictionary of dictionaries, list of dictionaries...), and how can I remove the old items?

Comment: What format is the timestamp?

Comment: @Pyson It's a datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a list of tuples. Alternatively, you could define a class to represent the entries. I often use the collections module's namedtuple for this sort of thing.

```
import datetime
import collections

Entry = collections.namedtuple('Entry', ['date', 'location'])

entries = []

entries.append(Entry(datetime.datetime.now(), "Siberia"))
entries.append(Entry(datetime.datetime.now(), "Wisconsin"))
```

For the purge you might take advantage of a generator expression qualified by a timedelta threshold. Here I use slice assignment to modify the list in place in order to keep the original `entries` reference intact.

```
threshold = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
entries[:] = (e for e in entries if now - e.date < threshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list of lists or a list of objects (classes).

You would do that like this:

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, date, location):
        self.date = date
        self.location = location

mylist = []
mylist.append(Entry(some_date, some_location))
```

where some_date and some_location are actual date and location.

Answer (score 0):

No need for classes when you just have to store two values:

```
data = []
#add elements:
data.append(("New York", "2013-10-31"))
data.append(("Washington", "2014-10-31"))
#cleanup (insert fancier date handling method here):
data = [element for element in data if element[0][:4] == "2014"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, date, location):
    self.date = date
    self.location = location

    def age(self):
        return datetime.now() - self.date
```

For the deletion part, here is an example:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(Entry(datetime.now(), 'here'))
mylist.append(Entry(datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=24), 'here'))
mylist.append(Entry(datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=26), 'here'))
#Show all entries
for i in mylist:
    print(i.age())
#delete entries older than 24 hours
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x.age() < timedelta(hours=24)]
#Show again :)
for i in mylist:
    print(i.age())
```

Answer (score 0):

This way seems simpler and faster than the other proposals. You have to compare both the date and the time. Let's assume you have a list of tuples each having two entries: date, and location. Since you will be adding the new tuples to the end of the list using "append", you can stop deleting when you get to the place where the date is no longer 24 hours old. Purging the list each time you add a new tuple will keep the list small and the effort (time) will also be small. If you start your project with a list that is not in time order you can do a one-time sort to make it so.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

n = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)

for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i][0] < n:
        del myList[i]
    else:
        break
```